# Criando um DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdown

Estou usando asp.net-mvc-5, e queria saber como faço para criar um DropdownList sem ser neste padrão aqui:

```
        <div id="conteudoEscolha">
            @Html.DropDownList("", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "Musico" })
        </div>
```

ou seja, não quero usar o @html.DropDownList, pois irei alimentá-lo usando javascript. Posso estar enganado, mas da maneira que eu fiz a cima está dando erro quando entro na tela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz conforme dito pelo @MarcoVinicius e então exibiu a mesnagem a baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ta sim ta sem nome!!! Por isso do erro

Comment: Lembrando que isso não limita mexer com Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você não pode passar null

passe

```
new List<SelectListItem>()

@Html.DropDownList("batata", new List<SelectListItem>(), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "Musico" })
```

se você quiser pode instanciar na sua controler desta maneira

```
var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
selectList.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "Selecione", Value = ""});

ViewBag.SelectList = selectList;
```

e na view ficaria

```
@Html.DropDownList("batata",  (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "Musico" })
```

Comment: Fiz conforme disse, e então apareceu a mensagem a baixo da primeira imagem (Editei a pergunta). Valeu

Comment: Editei utilize desta maneira

Comment: O Erro Parou de ser apontado, mas quando rodo, a aplicação ainda diz estar nula ou vazia: **An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Value cannot be null or empty.**

Comment: a dropdown precisa ter um name

Comment: Deu certo, valeu